# Magento breaks whenever collectTotals is called

Tags: quote, ee-1.13, debugging

My cart recently started not working anymore and I have narrowed it down to the collectTotals method in Mage_Sales_Model_Quote model. It happens when it calls collectTotals on the shipping address. I am not really sure where to go from here or what would be the best way to debug this moving forward.

If anyone has has this similar issue or would know of a good way to further debug this situation that would be awesome.

Also I am using EE 1.13.0.2

Comment: This should be referred to Enterprise support. Have you installed any modules?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps: [1.9 sample data checkout issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/21096/146). I had the same issue with ce 1.9 because the USPS shipping method was enabled but no valid credentials were provided.

Check the shipping methods section in system->configuration and disable the ones that you are not using.