# Checkout Error magento 1.9, can't continue to shipping information

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I know there are multiple topics concerning this subject but I can't get my error fixed. I was on magento 1.8, everything was working great but suddenly I got the problem that in the checkout module, I can't continue to Shipping Information. 
Continue just doesn't do anything. Unless (and now the fun part starts) I use Ship to Different adress (bottom option). Then it DOES continue. I have upgraded to 1.9 but same problem. I can't find any errors (not in the log, in magento or apache and not in the JS, f12 in chrome), it works using the default template but my template only has the files in the checkout folder:

```
success.phtml
cart.phtml
onepage/login.phtml
multishipping/success.phtml
multishipping/shipping.phtml
multishipping/overview.phtml
multishipping/billing.phtml
```

cart/some irrelevent files i guess

My template realy doesn't do that much i recon!

I know this isn't a really high quality post but is there anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just disable usps shipping method from admin check this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21096/1-9-sample-data-checkout-issue

Comment: Fixed, normal checkout doesn't work but after deleting and installing OPC plugin this plugin seems to work.

Answer (score 6):

found this solution and it worked for me :-)

> After look in everywhere I found out it was just an update on the
>   layout. I went to
>   /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
>   and changed that around the line 36:

adding the id “checkout-payment-method-load” to fieldset so change line 36 from 
`fieldset`
to 
`fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load"`

source:
http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/index.php/magento-1-8-payment-not-loading-on-checkout/

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below code inside the **Form** in this path

> `app/design/frontend/<package/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`

```
<div class="fieldset" ">
        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('methods_additional', '', true, true) ?>
      <fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
            </fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Surely the above won't work as the html breaks on the 1st line:
<div class="fieldset" ">